# VB.NET Interface Property with Getter but no Setter

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, properties, interface, c#-to-vb.net

I wonder how I could do an Interface with Read only property  in VB.NET?

In C# I'd do something like:

```
interface ISomething {
    int PropNeeded { get; }
}
```

But when I try to do the same in VB

```
Interface ISomething
    Property PropNeeded() As Integer
        Get
        End Get
    End Property 
End Interface
```

I got this error message from Visual Studio 2010: *"Statement cannot appear within an interface body. End of interface assumed.*"

Which seems logic, since it's like I tried to give an implementation to the Property... But it's important that the Property has no Setter only a Getter.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Readonly Property PropNeeded() As Integer
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed simple :P

Answer (score 2):

```
Interface ISomething
      ReadOnly Property PropNeeded() As Integer
End Interface
```

As a side note, you can use C# to VB online code converters. [Telerik code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: I think the link to the Telerik code converter will be very useful, thanks!

Comment: Indeed it is. Makes life a lot easier for somebody experienced in C#, and newbie in VB.NET. There are other online converters also.